# Dynamic controls

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have the following function that cycles through controls on a form to store the useful data into a string array. It skips by 2 because the first control is a label. The second control can be a textbox or checkbox. My function allows me to gather all the textbox information but not the checkboxes. How could I modify my function to gather checkbox information? I could use anything like True / False, Checked / Unchecked, etc.

```
Public Function createInput() As String()
    Dim int = myControls.Length
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim str(int) As String
    For i = 1 To int - 1 Step 2
        str(count) = myControls(i).Text
        count += 1
    Next
    Return str
 End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How could I modify my function to gather checkbox information?

You can use the OfType extension on the Controls collection, assuming myControls is a controls collection:

```
For Each cb As CheckBox in myControls.OfType(Of CheckBox)

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check type of object and act accordingly

```
Public Function createInput() As String()
    Dim int = myControls.Length
    Dim count As Integer = 0

    Dim ctrlData As New List(Of String)()
    For Each c As Control In myControls
        If TypeOf c Is TextBox Then  
            ctrlData.Add(c.Text)
        ElseIf TypeOf c Is CheckBox Then
            ctrlData.Add(DirectCast(c, CheckBox).Checked)
        ElseIf TypeOf c Is ListBox Then
            Dim lb As ListBox = DirectCast(c, ListBox)
            If lb.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
                ctrlData.Add(lb.SelectedValue)
            End If
        ElseIf . . .  . . Then
              . . .  . 
        Else 
              . .  . . . . 
        End if
    Next
    Return ctrlData.ToArray() ' <-- Note that List is more flexible than array
End Function
```

This is reference you were looking for: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4zz68xc.aspx